# No write access on second HDD when changing to Kubuntu OS

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu

I have a laptop with 2 HDD drives, an M.2 SSD and a SATA SSD. I was using Windows 10, but I changed to Kubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I installed the OS to a complete new M.2 SSD, and I let the SATA HDD as it was with the files (as when I used it on the windows). The problem now is that when I try to write to the files on the SATA HDD, I cannot due to access privileges. I looked at the properties labels and I haven't succeeded in changing this. Any ideas? I am googling it but I do not find a similar situation.

Comment: How do you mount the HDD?

Comment: I am not sure... But if this helps: I opened the laptop, I disconnected ( ejected) the SATA HDD, I installed the OS to the m.2 ssd. When everything of the Kubuntu installed correctly, I opened the laptop and I connected the SATA ssd. And the OS sees it, I can access the files of the sata hdd but not change them.

Comment: How is the HDD formatted? Is it NTFS?

Comment: It was used on Windows 10, so I assume yes, NTFS..

Comment: Then the problem must be that you didn't shut down Windows properly before you removed it.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/532753/167850

Comment: Ok I read the thread, very risky... I am about to eject the SATA ssd from the laptop, and copy the data to another hdd (a backup one) in order to format the SATA ssd and the connect it to the laptop. One question...if I press "unmount" and then "mount" on the SATA hdd, can this solve the problem?

Comment: It is not "very risky". But your plan is good. Backup your data and format the HDD to some linux FS, like ext4. Unmount and mount won't fix anything.

Comment: If I delete from the OS inside, instead of opening the laptop removing the SATA SSD and format it with a SATA to USB adapter, it is the same thing right?

Comment: There is no need to take it out and use an adapter. But it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Ok, here is the solution to my problem. I opened the laptop, I removed the SATA HDD, I used a USB to SATA adapter and I connect it to a Windows 10 OS, then I safely removed the HDD and I disassembled from the adapter. I connected back to the Linux OS laptop, and turned it on. It works perfectly now.

Comment: A perfect solution. Write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the solution to my problem. I opened the laptop, I removed the SATA HDD, I used a USB to SATA adapter and I connect it to a Windows 10 OS, then I safely removed the HDD and I disassembled from the adapter. I connected back to the Linux OS laptop, and turned it on. It works perfectly now. No backup, no copy-paste.

Comment: But be aware that having an NTFS disk without Windows installed is not a good practice. If the disk needs repair, you won't be able to do it inless you connect it to a Windows machine again. It is better to format it to something else.

Comment: Finally, I formatted it to ext4 because with NTFS I had problems.